# Apply changes from linked npm modules without rebuilding

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack

My webapp consists of two modules from separate git repos, with the following directory structure:

```
webapp/module1
webapp/module2
```

module1 depends on module2, so I've added the link:

```
cd webapp/module1
npm link ../module2
```

The module1 is main module, so I'm running webapp using `npm start` from there:

```
cd webapp/module1
npm start
```

`start` is configured in module1's `package.json` as follows:

```
{
    "scripts": {
        ...
        "start": "webpack-dev-server --open --progress --colors & npm run build:css -- -w",
        "build:css": "node-sass src/style/main.scss dist/webpage.min.css --output-style compressed"
    }
}
```

The problem is when I make a change to module2 source code editing its javascript sources - the change is not applied immediately to the running webapp instance. I need to execute `npm run build` manually:

```
cd webapp/module2
npm run build
```

`build` is configured in module2's `package.json` as follows:

```
"build": "cross-env WEBPACK_ENV=prod && npm run v:patch && webpack"
```

Only after this step the changes are applied to the webapp. Is there a way to get such changes to be applied automatically? I'm using npm version 5.6.0.

Comment: That's why I hate the JS stack - a huge number of absolutely ridiculous problems, a huge number of JS experts, but nobody knows how to solve these issues

Comment: You are right, you should be able to accomplish this without running a 2nd build. Can you describe more about how your project is setup? Are module1 & module2 sources actually part of your project or brought in via package.json? It doesn't sound like you are using `npm link` correctly. The way you use it is run `npm link` from the directory of the clone module (say it's named "foo") then from your project that depends on it, you run "npm link foo", and it will replace the package.json entry with a path to the symlink'd directory.

Comment: @olore thanks, but it doesn't matter, it behaves absolutely the same if you include as package.json or if you just add a dependency somewhere in code like index.html... it will not rebuild dependencies automatically if you will run npm link two times as you described as well

Comment: Can you share the repo? I'm afraid I can't help any further without it.

Comment: @olore yes, sure: https://github.com/artf/grapesjs-preset-webpage - it depends on npm linked modules like grapesjs-blocks-basic, grapesjs-navbar... which are resided in separate repositories on the same account: https://github.com/artf/grapesjs-blocks-basic, https://github.com/artf/grapesjs-navbar